# Correct TypeScript types for passing children props through a React higher order component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, type-inference, typescript-generics

Consider the following code, containing a higher order component, a functional component, and a component created using the HOC and our functional component:

```
interface InjectedProps {
  someProp?: number;
}

const myHoc = <P extends {}>(
  Component: ComponentType<P>
) => ({someProp, ...props}: P & InjectedProps) => {
  return <Component {...props as P} />;
}

const MyComponent = (props: {children?: React.ReactNode}) => {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};

const WrappedComponent = myHoc(MyComponent);
```

However, when we try and use this new `WrappedComponent`:

```
return (
  <WrappedComponent>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h2>World</h2>
  </WrappedComponent>
);
```

We end up with the error: `Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InjectedProps'.`.

This can be solved by injecting the `children` prop into the props of the HOC, like so;

```
interface InjectedProps {
  someProp?: number;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}
```

However, we now have the problem of **all wrapped components can now take on children**, even when they could previously not.

My question is, what is the proper typing for a higher order component which passes down the children in the wrapped component?

Answer (score 1):

You see this error because `P extends {}`, whereas it should extends `P extends { children?: React.ReactNode; }` because you want to provide `children`.

Btw, it is considered a bad practice to use just empty object `{}` as a generic constraint. You should use `Record<PropertyKey, unknown>` instead `{}`.

Also, you should use `ComponentType<Omit<P & InjectedProps, "someProp">>` instead of `ComponentType<P>` because this is how TS infers this type.

**Working code:**

```js
import React, { FC, ComponentType } from 'react'

interface InjectedProps {
    someProp?: number;
}

type WithChildren = {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const myHoc = <P extends WithChildren>(
    Component: ComponentType<Omit<P & InjectedProps, "someProp">>
) => ({ someProp, ...props }: P & InjectedProps) => <Component {...props} />

const MyComponent: FC = (props) => <div>{props.children}</div>

const WrappedComponent = myHoc(MyComponent);

const App = () => (
    <WrappedComponent>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <h2>World</h2>
    </WrappedComponent>
)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwtoROBAHZIUwAqAnmEnAL5wBmUZcA5FKhh4AoIcBpIo7dMwCSFAFZIMSACYAFLmADOuIXH1wtZJBohgA-AC44FAK4gARhIDcQliJiNmAdWAwAFoT%20wAA2KvwUcAC8ugZwaMFhEVaIAjAAdMjoMAByECpIru5CaJRa8CD0ABIQaNFwADxqcEgAHjDUKjq%20AUGh4dQAfAAUegak5FQ01hOQU3ReDQDyIH5NcABkcHKKyuqaWtgAREYgJppHg4NCAJTRg3DDeKfnZtjpH2AHrNbNWztKDr7MxaO5RB4NWaUajwHAfdJfEFsAD01xKZXgAFl6FD5tYiPVhojtGCISpgAA3QY4YladIJfoRFgNZHkqkiUoUcpwbxQFBgJgqXEw%20qVGpoYbY4U0G6udFc%20AAQQFhNJjzG%20gavP5gulMGucTiDX8AEZBlUkCEQhAWaaDYbNf4AEyDbzQMK2l0axrI7UC1R6643IA)